# Unable to lock administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/)

Tags: dpkg

How to fix the error

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock – open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```